# How can I track/graph arcserver usage statistics?

Tags: arccatalog, arcgis-server, statistics

I’m currently using the ArcGIS Server Properties dialog in ArcCatalog to periodically check the usage statistics for our services.  I’d like to be able to chart those to get a big picture view of what’s going on.  Does anyone know the location on an ArcServer machine where a file with these statistics is being written, ideally something that could be pulled into a spreadsheet?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ArcGIS Server logs contain detailed information about server usage.  They're located in:

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server\user\log
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\user\log
```

They're XML files that you could load into a spreadsheet, but the data there might be a bit overwhelming, especially for a busy site.  Also, there will be at least one file per day; sometimes more.

Latitude Geographics (where I work) make a product called [Geocortex Optimizer](http://www.geocortex.com/gis-software/geocortex-optimizer/) that can digest your ArcGIS Server logs to report on server usage.

Answer (score 1):

I use [google analytics](https://www.google.com/accounts/ManageAccount)

[Analytics tour](http://services.google.com/analytics/tour/index_en-US.html)